# tanh-estimator Normalization in PYTHON

Tags: python, normalization

Does anybody know how to implement tanh-estimator in python? I have a list of numbers which doesn't follow gaussian distribution. I want to use tanh-estimator as the preprocessing step but i don't know how can i implement it in python since there is no defined function for it like MinMaxScaler().

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12):

There is an example of **@UrbanoFonseca**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46649984/6727571):

```
import numpy as np

unnormalizedData = np.array([[15, 60], [5, 15], [45, 0], [0, 30]], dtype=np.float64)

m = np.mean(unnormalizedData, axis=0) # array([16.25, 26.25])
std = np.std(unnormalizedData, axis=0) # array([17.45530005, 22.18529919])

data = 0.5 * (np.tanh(0.01 * ((unnormalizedData - m) / std)) + 1)
#array([[0.49712291, 0.5076058 ],
#       [0.49711136, 0.49746456],
#       [0.50865938, 0.4940842 ],
#       [0.49710558, 0.50084515]])
```

Note this code implement a modified tanh-estimators proposed in *Efficient approach to Normalization of Multimodal Biometric Scores*, 2011

In the original version, the mean and standard deviation are estimated by Hampel estimators (*Robust Statistics: The Approach Based on Influence Functions*, 1986)

Comment: If I'm right - the values are always close to 0.5, if they are close to mean ?

Answer (score 8):

I followed the paper 'Efficient approach to Normalization of Multimodal Biometric Scores' (2011) of L.Latha and S.Thangasamy. You can check it [here](http://research.ijcaonline.org/volume32/number10/pxc3875530.pdf).

They propose a modified version which avoids the complexity of the Hampel estimators, by using the mean and standard deviation of the scores instead.

The formula is:
tanh s' = 0.5[tanh(0.01(s-μ)/σ) + 1]

Using numpy you can use:

- np.mean() for the μ
- np.std() for the σ
- np.tanh() for the tanh function

Comment: What is the formula for s-prime? How do you get rid of the tanh on the left side - or is there another trick?